# How to set up kaggle api in colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am uploading the `kaggle.json` file for every new session in Google Colab. Is there any way to permanently configure it using Google Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save kaggle.json in gdrive, mount it, then download from there.

You can also embed kaggle.json directly in Colab.

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!echo '{"username":"korakot","key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}' > ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

If your notebook is private(not shared), this is the most convenient way.

Comment: This seems to resolve the question. @vilas, could you confirm? or share with us your comments?